# using jwt token, how to share user permissions between microservices if permission are too many and i dont want to put them into jwt token?

Tags: asp.net-core, microservices

i have identity server that provide access token to the login user and api(multiple) that have bearer token authentication but in case of authorization I need to know how to authorize user by using user permissions and not only client scopes. the issue here is to load those permisions from authorization server independent from identity server because user might have to many permissions that can not be added into access token through IProfileService. I tried to add those permission into access token but it caused the token to be too large and request header has limitation of 8kb and 16kb in IIS server.
I was thinking of using IDistributedCache for sharing user permissions but I dont think it is a better solution.

Comment: How about a kind of permissions API microservice? Your other services would call it to ask for those permissions when needed.

Comment: thanks! its a good idea but im afraid that all microservice that user pemissions api will be tighly coupled with permision api.  my concern is every request to the api will call permission api to verify for the user permission of login user or the permission will be called once and store in in memory cache so that if the same comes again his/her permissions will be already stored in cache so that to minimize number of request between my-microservice and permission api service

Comment: Yeah there isn't really an optimal solution for performance vs freshness of permissions with this, you have to decide what is an acceptable delay for updating permissions. A higher delay allows services to cache permissions longer.